# Getting uikit consistency error using essentials

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Im using essentials to get information about screen size but since few days i´ve been getting this error.

```
uikit consistency error: you are calling a uikit method that can only be invoked from the ui thread
```

The error is being thrown in this line of code

```
var screenSize = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width + "x" + DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height
```

I didnt understood why this error start showing up suddently because it was never happening before. I believe this started to happen as soon as i updated my visual studio.

I was reading through the xamarin documentation about UIThreads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread and it says there that this error will only shows up in debugg and not in release versions so my question is.

Does this means that the app will still work normally in release or the error will not show like it says on the docs but it´s still there and it will prevent that line of code to work?

i think that i have to do something like this to stop showing that error but im wondering if i keep that as it is if it will work in release

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
var screenSize = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width + "x" + DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height
});
```

Comment: `...if it will work in release...` : yes, it will

Comment: @SushiHangover But if it will still work in release why is xamarin advising to run that on MainThread? It´s just because it will not work in debbug? And when running a release version does the xamarin automatically deals with this in order for that specific line of code to work? 
Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: UIKit calls within iOS have to run on he UIThread/Main thread and no, the code within that part of Essentials does not force the code to run on the main thread, it is up to the programmer to decide when it is needed based upon where the call is made within your code:  https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/b018723477f848b108cb9a67adecb3608d0ab686/Xamarin.Essentials/DeviceDisplay/DeviceDisplay.ios.cs

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the release builds, Xamarin won't check for the problem and it won't throw a managed exception. However, you will have a native crash, don't worry.

However your last lines should work and shouldn't cause any kind of crashes whether debug or release:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
var screenSize = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width + "x" + DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height
});
```

As long as Essentials are working properly regarding this, there is built-in way in Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS to handle this so I've never tried how Essentials do that...